# Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(3^k-2k)}{3k+k^2}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to figure out whether or not the following series is convergent: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(3^k-2k)}{3k+k^2}$$

Now, I know from the back of the book that it is divergent, but I haven't been able to show it. I think I am supposed to compare it to some other series, but I don't know which one. I have tried looking at the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ but that integral was really hard to solve (haven't managed it) which makes me think that there should be an easier way.

In general, I am having some trouble with this type of exercise where I should use comparison tests. I never know what I should compare it to.

Comment: We have $3^k-2k=3^k(1-2k/3^k)$, so the ln is $k\ln 3+\ln(1-2k/3^k)$.

Comment: Compare with the Harmonic Number.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use  Asymptotic Comparison Test
 $$0\leq\frac{\ln(3^k-2k)}{3k+k^2}\sim \frac{\ln(3^k)}{k^2}=\frac{\ln(3)}{k}.$$

Comment: ... or you can use the P-Series/Integral Test once you've compared it :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Don't you want a lower bound?

Comment: @DonAntonio: A divergent series as an upper bound is not so helpful. One has to make it a lower bound.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi Of course, thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm an idiot, but I don't see the big difference between the answer from Robert Z and the one from DonAntonio, except for the notation. If $\frac{\ln(3^k-2k)}{3k+k^2}$ is smaller than $\frac{ln(3^k)}{k^2}$, then does it suffice to show that $\frac{ln(3^k)}{k^2}$ diverges?

Answer (score 2):

The bog-standard comparison test works well too. Note that (for $k \ge 3$)
\begin{align*}
\frac{\log(3^k - 2k)}{3k+k^2} &\ge \frac{\log(3^k - \frac{1}{2}3^k)}{3k^2+k^2}\\
&=\frac{\log(\frac{1}{2}3^k)}{4k^2}\\
&=\frac{\log(3)}{4k} - \frac{\log(2)}{4k^2}
\end{align*}
and hence the sequence diverges.